# iOS certificate that doesn't invalidate after 7 days?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've created an app that I'm using for research for general data collection/exporting. As of right now I have to reinstall the app every 7 days or so because the certificate it's signed with becomes invalid and it crashes on startup. From what I can tell the only way to achieve this is to buy a developer license. I just wanted to make sure there was no other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ll have to sign up for a paid Apple Developer account. Then your apps can be tested for a year before having to be reloaded, you have access to more in-app capabilities and can submit apps to the App Store. Hope this helps.